# PHP working with huge numbers

Tags: php, int

I am writing an application that can stream videos.  It requires the filesize of the video, so I use this code:

```
$filesize = sprintf("%u", filesize($file));
```

However, when streaming a six gig movie, it fails.

Is is possible to get a bigger interger value in PHP?  I don't care if I have to use third party libraries, if it is slow, all I care about is that it can get the filesize properly.

FYI, `$filesize` is currently 3017575487 which is really really really really far from 6000000000, which is roughly correct.

I am running PHP on a 64 bit operating system.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: If you're using 64-bit PHP on a 64-bit operating system

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes I am using a 64 bit operating system.

Comment: @MarkBaker It says when I run phpinfo that it is using 86x architecture.  I am running XAMPP.

Comment: Check the value of the PHP_INT_MAX or PHP_INT_SIZE constants

Comment: @MarkBaker  PHP_INT_MAX is 2147483647, PHP_INT_SIZE is 4???

Comment: `echo (PHP_INT_SIZE == 4) ? "32-bit" : ((PHP_INT_SIZE == 8) ? "64-Bit" : "PHP_INT_SIZE is " . PHP_INT_SIZE);`

Comment: So you're on 32-bit PHP 4bytes x 8 bits = 32 bits

Comment: @MarkBaker Yeah, but I checked it up - XAMPP does not come with 64 bit windows, and PHP 64 bit windows is experimental...

Comment: Without switching to 64-bit PHP, the limit of a signed integer in PHP will always be 32-bits

Comment: @MarkBaker So you can't even use third party libraries?

Comment: If you use exec to do a DIR from the command line, you'll get the result back as a string, including the filesize information... parse that string to extract the filesize component as a string

Comment: Or switch from using xampp (which shouldn't be used in production anyway) to a 64-bit Windows PHP binary.... if this isn't a production system, why worry about "experimental"

Comment: @MarkBaker how do you parse the string and extract the filesize component?  I still need to do division...etc on the number.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is two-fold.

## Problem 1

---

The [`filesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) function returns a signed integer, with a maximum value of [`PHP_INT_MAX`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php). On 32-bit PHP, this value is `2147483647` or about 2GB. On 64-bit PHP can you go higher, up to `9223372036854775807`. Based on the comments from the [PHP `filesize` page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php), I created a function that will use a `fseek` loop to find the size of the file, and return it as a `float`, which can count higher that a 32-bit unisgned integer.

```
function filesize_float($filename)
{
    $f = fopen($filename, 'r');
    $p = 0;
    $b = 1073741824;
    fseek($f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while($b > 1)
    {
        fseek($f, $b, SEEK_CUR);
        if(fgetc($f) === false)
        {
            fseek($f, -$b, SEEK_CUR);
            $b = (int)($b / 2);
        }
        else
        {
            fseek($f, -1, SEEK_CUR);
            $p += $b;
        }
    }
    while(fgetc($f) !== false)
    {
        ++$p;
    }
    fclose($f);
    return $p;
}
```

To get the file size of the file as a float using the above function, you would call it like this.

```
$filesize = filesize_float($file);
```

## Problem 2

---

Using `%u` in the [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function will cause it to interpret the argument as an unsigned integer, thus limiting the maximum possible value to `4294967295` on 32-bit PHP, before overflowing. Therefore, if we were to do the following, it would return the wrong number.

```
sprintf("%u", filesize_float($file));
```

You could interpret the value as a float using `%F`, using the following, but it will result in trailing decimals.

```
sprintf("%F", filesize_float($file));
```

For example, the above will return something like `6442450944.000000`, rather than `6442450944`.

A workaround would be to have `sprintf` interpret the float as a string, and let PHP cast the float to a string.

```
$filesize = sprintf("%s", filesize_float($file));
```

This will set `$filesize` to the value of something like `6442450944`, without trailing decimals.

## The Final Solution

---

If you add the `filesize_float` function above to your code, you can simply use the following line of code to read the actual file size into the `sprintf` statement.

```
$filesize = sprintf("%s", filesize_float($file));
```

Comment: I tested it out: The script terminated with a timeout error.  Removing the timeout error makes it execute forever: I have tried up to one hour.

Comment: @Nathan How strange. Are you sure it is a problem with this code? That is the exact file size you are using it on?

Answer (score 0):

As per PHP docuemnation for 64 bit platforms, this seems quite reliable for getting the filesize of files > 4GB

```
<?php 
$a = fopen($filename, 'r'); 
fseek($a, 0, SEEK_END); 
$filesize = ftell($a); 
fclose($a); 
?>
```

Comment: It returns 0, but thanks for the reply anyway.  When you say 64 bit platforms does that include PHP, or just the os?

Comment: Its should work can you please check this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

Comment: Nope. However, for files smaller than that it does.  Note that though my computer is 64 bit, my PHP version is 32 bit.

Comment: ftell() will still return an integer value: if that value falls outside of the 32-bit limit for a signed integer, then it won't work